# Sending selected word into a list file

Tags: windows, android

Is there any software on `windows` and `android` which can send selectable word `(string)` to list file. I will use it to learn new words in a foreign language.
For example select a word in a webpage and send it to a list.
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "selectable" word (string)? Do you mean you want to select some words from a text and export them to a list, or list all the words of a text, or something else?

Comment: Dear, an example is added.